# searchDisplayController: change the label "No Results"

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, searchdisplaycontroller

how do I change the label "No Results", when using a searchDisplayController?

Regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not directly accessible, so you'll have to do it the old fashioned way and manually sift through the subviews of your `searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView`. Here's one example:

```
UITableView *tableView = self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;
for( UIView *subview in tableView.subviews ) {
     if( [subview class] == [UILabel class] ) {
         UILabel *lbl = (UILabel*)subview; // sv changed to subview.
         lbl.text = @"My custom string";
     }
}
```

I wouldn't recommend this since you're relying on internal behavior of the `searchResultsTableView` which is more than likely going to change at some point, breaking your app. Opening a bug/feature request with Apple would be a good way to go here.

Comment: But when do you do the tweaking? This `UILabel` pops up in the `subviews` only after it has been actually displayed...

Comment: I put this in `- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`. It works.

Comment: Thanks alot , u saved my time

Answer (score 14):

I've successfully removed the label by never having an empty result set.

If there are no results because they're being fetched from the server, reset your data source to a single row, and have it display a blank table view cell.

Additionally, use logic to refeuse to select the "dummy" cell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *listItem = [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([listItem isEqualToString:@""]) {
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
}
```

I've also found it necessary to add "dummy" cell logic into the `willSelect` delegate method:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *listItem = [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([listItem isEqualToString:@""]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return indexPath;
}
```