# How to remove No Result TableView of UITableViewCell in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisearchbar

Actually my TableView's background color is really black.
However when i use SearchBar and search words,if there is no data that match , there will appear "NO Result" UITableView with White Color.
I don't want to appear that White color background with " NO Result " TableViewCell if there are no match words..
How can i remove that White UITableViewCell?

That No Result TableView is i want to remove if there are no result that match.
[image]

Comment: Would be helpful to see your code so far...

Comment: Take a look at those two related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451945/uitableview-change-no-results-message  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165224/searchdisplaycontroller-change-the-label-no-results

Answer (score 2):

That tableView comes automatic since it's part of the search, however you can modify by doing this:

1. Create a boolean flag named **noResultsToDisplay** (or something else).
2. If you have no results to display then set `noResultsToDisplay = YES`, set it to `NO` otherwise.
3. In **numberOfRowsInSection**, `if (noResultsToDisplay) return 3;`
4. In **cellForRowAtIndexPath**, `if (noResultsToDisplay && indexPath.row == 2) cell.textLabel.text = @"No Results";`